# Python type hints: should I use more generic types?

Tags: python-3.x

With Python 3 type hints, should I be using the more generic types as opposed to the more concrete ones?  For example

```
a: Sequence[str] = []
```

as opposed to:

```
a: List[str] = []
```

I'm thinking "yes".  Which leads to the question of when would I want to use the more concrete type?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just answered my own question.

I had a Sequence declared like this:

```
a: Sequence[str] = []
```

but then I had a need to append items to it.  Sequence doesn't have this method defined for it and thus mypy complained.  So, I think the answer is "use the generic type by default and drop down to the concrete type when you need to".